# Let $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism, show $\varphi':G\rightarrow\text{im}(\varphi)$ is an epimorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism, show $\varphi':G\rightarrow\text{im}(\varphi)$ is an epimorphism

Epimorphism is a surjective homorphism. We know that $\text{im}(\varphi)\subseteq H$ from the image definition.

Surjective $\varphi'$ is defined as $\forall h_1\in\text{im}(\varphi),\exists g_1\in G,\text{such that},\varphi'(g_1)=h_1$

We can assume that $\varphi'$ is a homomorphism since the codomain of $\varphi'$ is a subset of the codomain of $\varphi$.

To show surjectivity I said that we know $\forall h_2\in H,\exists g_2\in G,\text{such that},\varphi(g_2)=h_2$. Since $\text{im}(\varphi)\subseteq H$, $\forall h_1\in \text{im}(\varphi),\exists g_1\in G,\text{such that},\varphi'(g_1)=h_1$ since every required mapping would have existed in $H$, therefore exists for $\text{im}(\varphi)$.

How should I explain this answer more concisely, and do I need to use all of the different subscripts for elements in $G,H$ and $\text{im}(\varphi)$. Can my answer be better phrased and have I missed any steps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about homomorphisms there. This is true for every function:

> If $f:X \to Y$ is a function, then $f$ induces a surjective function $X \to Z$ onto its image $Z=f(X)$.

The function $g:X \to Z$ is defined by $g(x)=f(x)$. Then:

- $g$ indeed goes to $Z$, because $g(x)=f(x)\in f(X)=Z$.
- $g$ is surjective, because given $z_0\in Z=f(X)$, we have $z_0=f(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in X$. But then $z_0=f(x_0)=g(x_0)$.